# Getting the predominant colour in an image?

Tags: images, colors, imagemagick, image-processing

Is it possible to get the predominant colour in an image from the command line? Ideally I'd like it back as hex or RGB.

I thought it might be possible to do this with [imagemagick's identify command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php), but I couldn't see an option for doing this in the documentation.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is a predominant color for you? 24-bit RGB pixel has 16777216 possible color values and I doubt if finding the most repeating one is useful in any way.

Comment: I'd like to narrow it down to a fairly small number of colours... I'm no expert on colours, but the sixteen HTML safe colours or the X11 colour names would be ideal. I guess this would need some kind of process like (i) reduce the colour space of the image (ii) create a table of pixels by colour (iii) map the dominant colour to the closest colour name. No idea how to do any of that, though!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imagemagick's `identify -verbose` provides a palette histogram table, *but* only if the number of unique colors is below a limit (1024 in the versions I've checked, v6.x up to v6.8.3).

Instead you can just "`convert`" your [image to a histogram](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#extract), this output is not limited by number of unique colors:

```
convert image.jpg  -format %c -depth 8  histogram:info:histogram_image.txt
sort -n histogram_image.txt | tail -1
```

Sorting the output numerically by the first column sorts by frequency of pixel colors. (Frequency of specific colour pixels might not correspond to a human perception of predominant color of course.)

If you're reducing colors, you can probably just trust `convert` to [do it for you](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/) by your choice of [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering#Digital_photography_and_image_processing) and/or [posterizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization). Even specifically to the web-safe 216:

```
convert image.png  +dither -remap netscape:  image_websafe.png
```

You would probably get closer to a perceived predominant color by some combination of blurring, resizing and posterizing, this is not a simple problem to define and solve:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16936
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421863/get-dominant-colors-from-image-discarding-the-background

---

See also the following link for `dcolors`, a script which uses Imagemagick to determine a set of predominant *colors* in an image, uses include coordinating your desktop color scheme with your chosen desktop image:
 http://javier.io/blog/en/2015/09/30/using-imagemagick-and-kmeans-to-find-dominant-colors-in-images.html

Comment: Thanks - great answer and the first two commands actually work pretty well! One final question: what do you think is the best way to map the predominant hex value to the nearest websafe value? Is this just a question of hex arithmetic or is there a more sophisticated way?

Comment: Given the palette is so limited, treating (R,G,B) as a 3d space and finding the minimal Euclidean distance to a defined colour would probably suffice for most purposes. You can get `convert` to do this for you by adding `-remap netscape:` after `-depth 8` in the first command above.

Comment: it might work better to convert to the HSV colour space, then only consider the "H" portion in the histogram.  Is this possible with IM?

Comment: You can add "`-colorspace HSV`" before `-format` in the first example to show HSV instead of sRGB in the histogram output, but you will need to process the hsv() values separately I think. If you use `-modulate 0,0,100` to perform a transform in HSL or HSV, you get a zero hue too, per-spec. Perhaps something smarter using `-fx` or `-color-matrix` could work, but that's beyond me today...

Comment: on windows, this should be run through `Cygwin`

Answer (score 7):

I found this elegant and short answer here http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/04/determining-dominant-image-color.html

```
$ convert Waffle.jpg -scale 1x1\! -format '%[pixel:u]' info:-
rgb(219,166,94)
```

Comment: It doesn't work any more

Comment: I think I properly updated the command to work with `magick` instead of the original `convert` command.